# how do i convert int to date in specific form?

Tags: java, time

i have an int number I need to convert it to a date but in  this form

("few seconds ago" ,"few minutes ago","few hours ago""yesterday","a few days ago","last week","last month","last year")

i can get the date

```
        int seconds =1320105600;

        int  millis = seconds * 1000;
        Date date = new Date(millis);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE,MMMM d,yyyy h:mm,a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
```

how can i convert it to that form

Comment: Get the current time, compare it with your date and decide what time intervals will correspond to your strings, e.g. less than 60 seconds difference == "a few seconds ago"

Comment: I've never tried this library, but from its description it seems to do what you need: http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get the difference in days, minutes, and seconds between two dates using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

```
java.util.Date d1, d2;

DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(d1);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(d2);

int numDays = Days.daysBetween(dt1, dt2).getDays(); 
int hours = Hours.hoursBetween(dt1, dt2).getHours() % 24;
int minutes = Minutes.minutesBetween(dt1, dt2).getMinutes() % 60);
int seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(dt1, dt2).getSeconds() % 60);

if (numDays > 0) { return "A few days ago"; }
else if (hours > 0) { return "A few hours ago"; }
// And so on
```

You should be able to adapt this pattern wihtout much effort to your specific requirements (there are `Years.yearsBetweeen` and `Months.monthsBetween` methods).

Answer (score 1):

You should create a function to do so:

```
int currentSeconds = ((int) System.currentTimeMillis())/ 1000;
int diff = currentSeconds - seconds;
if (diff < 60)
    formatedDate = "Few seconds ago";
else if (diff < 60 * 60)
    formatedDate = "Few minutes ago";
```

And so on.

Comment: I guess it should be diff in the if clause and not currentSeconds

Comment: Yep, sorry about that